# MariaDB/PGSQL transaction lock

Tags: mysql, postgresql, mariadb, deadlock

I am trying to produce this PGSQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1 FOR NO KEY UPDATE;
```

Into a MySQL syntax but I can't figure out how. I have a constraint on a foreign key, I need to tell to MySQL that my update query won't affect the primary key but another column.
Right now MySQL thinks that transaction 1 will affect the ID so it won't let transaction 2 update my table as its locked. This is doable with PG `FOR NO KEY UPDATE` but i can't figure it out with MySQL.

dump:

```
CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
      `id` bigint PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `owner` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `balance` bigint NOT NULL,
      `currency` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT (now())
    );

CREATE TABLE `entries` (
  `id` bigint PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `amount` bigint NOT NULL COMMENT 'can be negative or positive',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT (now())
);

CREATE TABLE `transfers` (
  `id` bigint PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `from_account_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `to_account_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `amount` bigint NOT NULL COMMENT 'must be posivite',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT (now())
);

CREATE INDEX `accounts_index_0` ON `accounts` (`owner`);

CREATE INDEX `entries_index_1` ON `entries` (`account_id`);

CREATE INDEX `transfers_index_2` ON `transfers` (`from_account_id`);

CREATE INDEX `transfers_index_3` ON `transfers` (`to_account_id`);

CREATE INDEX `transfers_index_4` ON `transfers` (`from_account_id`, `to_account_id`);

ALTER TABLE `entries` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`account_id`) REFERENCES `accounts` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `transfers` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`from_account_id`) REFERENCES `accounts` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `transfers` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`to_account_id`) REFERENCES `accounts` (`id`);
```

EDIT: To clarify, update query from 2nd transaction is: `UPDATE accounts SET balance = ? WHERE id = ?` and it causes deadlock.

Comment: How does a select statement update any table? `I need to tell to MySQL that my update query won't affect the primary key` :: what update?

Comment: Sorry it might be confusing. My update query is: `UPDATE accounts SET balance = ? WHERE id = ?`. This is causing a deadlock when running concurrently two transactions. But this is not the case in PGSQL when transaction 1 is doing SELECT with the query provided in my initial post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use
SELECT ... FOR SHARE for INNODB.
Refer: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html for further details.

Comment: Thanks. I looked into this `FOR SHARE` but this is not helping me, this is giving me an error: `Error 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SHARE' at line 4`, query is: `SELECT * FROM accounts
WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1
FOR SHARE;`

Comment: For clarity you should use MariaDB rather than MySQL in the question. The MariaDB [manual](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/select/) shows " LOCK IN SHARE MODE" as the syntax.

Comment: I tried `LOCK IN SHARE MODE` it gives me a deadlock: `Error 1213 (40001): Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction`.